# Serial port /dev/cu.usbmodemfa131 vs /dev/cu.usbserial-A702NY8S

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-nano

On Mac OSX Mavericks, why does Arduino Uno uses serial port named `/dev/cu.usbmodemfa131` while Arduino Nano uses `/dev/cu.usbserial-A702NY8S`?

Are they using different FTDI drivers?

Comment: Which revision of the Arduino board do you have?

Comment: @AsheeshR Arduino Uno R3 and Sainsmart Arduino Nano v3

Comment: To throw another spanner in the works, have you ever noticed what happens to the serial port identifier when you put the Arduino Uno R3 into a different USB? For me 131 <--> 121. But if you change the Nano between ports, the identifier is the same!

Answer (score 2):

Drivers are different. On older boards, such as Duemilanove you may need to actually [download serial drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) to [talk to them](https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/tutorials/serial_terminal) at all in Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks.
There's some discussion of that problem [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=114652.0).

Answer (score 1):

It's really down to the manufacturer and what they identify their USB side as. I have found that Arduino(tm) provide a more meaningful (to me) identifier, eg `/dev/cu.usbmodemfa131` Whilst the boards that use the FTDI chip have the more serialised numbers `/dev/cu.usbserial-A702NY8S`.

Answer (score 0):

The Uno is not using FTDI drivers **at all**, since it does USB through an ATmega16u2, not an FTDI chip.